# using zip with two dictionaries of different length

Tags: python, zip

```
A={1:[1],2:[2],3:[3]}

B= {1:[5]}

summ = [a[0]+b[0] for (a,b) in zip(A.values(),B.values())]

print(summ)

summ = [6]
```

I have the above situation where I would like to sum the values corresponding to the same KEYS **while** keeping the non corresponding values at the same time, so that the solution in this case would be:

```
summ = [6, 2, 3]
```

How can I do it? It is not mandatory to zip the dictionary, but that's what I tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A list comprehension should do the trick:

```
summ = [v[0] + B[k][0] if k in B else v[0] for k, v in A.items()]
```

Comment: you undirectly gave me a very good explanation. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
def sum_dicts(A: dict, B: dict):
    temp = {}
    for key in A.keys():
        temp[key] = A[key] + B[key] if key in B.keys() else A[key]
    
    for key in [key for key in B.keys() if key not in A.keys()]:
        temp[key] = B[key]

    return temp
```

This function takes two dicts and adds the values for the keys that exist in both, updating the temporary dict with values from each when there is no matching dict.